# Error when creating observer for textfield to enable/disable button (Swift 3, Xcode 8.x)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create an observer for when the specified text field ends editing in order to disable/enable a button that forwards to a new segue.

In the end, I want to have a button that is only enabled when the the textfield is full and finished editing, which will allow it to move on to the next VC.

The error that is showing is:

```
 Cannot call value of non-function type '((UITextFieldDelegate) -> (UITextField) -> Bool)?'
```

Here's my source code:

```
import UIKit

class EmailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// Back Button Two

@IBOutlet weak var backButtonTwo: UIButton!

// Email Header

@IBOutlet weak var emailSloganLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var emailDescSloganLabel: UILabel!

// Email Form Entries

@IBOutlet weak var emailAddressMiniHeader: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var emailAddressTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var emailAddressLineBreak: UILabel!

// Bottom Bar 'Next' Navigation

@IBOutlet weak var bottomNextButtonTwo: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var bottomNextLineBreakTwo: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    emailAddressTextField.delegate = self

    emailAddressTextField.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(UITextFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldEndEditing("textFieldDidChange:")), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

}


internal func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ emailAddressTextField: UITextField) -> Bool {  if self.emailAddressTextField.text == "" {
    self.bottomNextButtonTwo.isEnabled = false
} else {
    self.bottomNextButtonTwo.isEnabled = true
    }
    return true
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


// Hide keyboard when user touches the outside keyboard


  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
 }


// Hides keyboard when user pressed the 'Return' Key

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    emailAddressTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return (true)

}

}
```

Thank you for any help, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you try to modify the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` from `UITextFieldDelegate ` and add target to point to that??? Just revert it back to the default one

Comment: Like this? `emailAddressTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UITextFieldDelegate(textFieldDidChange:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)`

Comment: remove `addTarget ` and add `func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool` if you want to know when the textfield end editting

Comment: @Tj3n You're the greatest. Thanks for teaching me something new. I couldn't figure out from the Apple documentation but I realized when you said to remove the 'addTarget' that it was directly conflicting with the existing 'func textFieldShouldEndEditing (textField: UITextField) -> Bool'

Comment: you are welcome, i just put answer there since it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `addTarget` since it will conflict with the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `textFieldShouldEndEditing` and should use it directly to know when the textfield finish editting